# Insertion in php from android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, xml

I am inserting the data from android to mysql using php and json request. When the event fire it gives the exception in the logcat. I am sharing my clogcat with you so you can have better look and idea of what is going on , here is my logcat  :

> 10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 10-07 03:55:13.073:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   com.example.receiptorganizer.Registration$1.insert(Registration.java:78)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   com.example.receiptorganizer.Registration$1.onClick(Registration.java:58)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 10-07 03:55:13.073:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-07 03:55:13.073:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-07 03:55:13.073:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-07 03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-07
>   03:55:13.073: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I think you should have put some more effort into this before asking someone else to solve your problem. Simply pasting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ` into Google would have provided the answer for you. To understand the down votes please refer to the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes when you are handling a network call(making a webservice call) in the main thread i.e. in the UI thread of the application.

Use AsyncTask or Handler to manage your webservice call.

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Your async task class can be like this

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
          protected void onPreExecute()
          {           super.onPreExecute();
                    //display progressdialog.
          } 

           protected void doInBackground(Void ...params)
          {  
                //http request. do not update ui here

                return null;
          } 

           protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
          {     
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //dismiss progressdialog.
                    //update ui
          } 

}
```

about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

And you can use handler like this :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // network call here
        }
    });
```

Use of **AsyncTask** is a better solution.

Comment: thank you ,   so what will be the best solution for that ?

Comment: I have updated the answer,please see it

Comment: @shurti thank you right now i am not getting any error exception but the simulator said that application stopped working so its due to slow internet or anyother issue ?

Comment: @shurti can you please tell me why i am facing this ?

10-07 06:27:30.293: W/System.err(2829): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.10.101 refused
10-07 06:27:30.293: W/System.err(2829):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
10-07 06:27:30.293: W/System.err(2829):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)

Comment: if you are using emulator to run your app for local server. mention the local ip as 10.0.2.2 and have to give Internet permission into your app

Answer (score 0):

Please look for this exception in google android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException or just follow a [tutroial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

use AsyncTask or Thread to call webservice to send data from your application.